# Want all social networking logos on same line in right side and company name and company logo on left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[social networking logo must appear horizontally not vertically. social networking logos should appear on right horizontally and company's name and logo must appear on left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiHZr.jpg)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class='col-md-12-fluid' style="
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
">
    <div class='col-md-8-fluid'>

        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4-fluid'style="
    margin-top: 3px;">
        <a><img height="180px" src="images/facebook.png" class="img-responsive"/></a>
        <a><img height="180px" src="images/twitter.png" class="img-responsive"/></a>
        <a><img height="180px" src="images/google.png" class="img-responsive"/></a>
        <a><img height="180px" src="images/pinterest.png" class="img-responsive"/></a>

        </div></div>


        <div class='clearfix'> </div>

    <div class="navbar-header">
```

Comment: just addnig this CSS would work, I think `.img-responsive{float:left;}`

Answer (score -1):

add your ul element class "navbar-right"

Comment: Your answer is unclear. If you decide to answer a question, please make sure that it is a complete sentence.

Comment: why is unclear? you only needs to add menu-right to ul section, but menu-header leaves on right

Comment: There is no `ul` element in the code... Also, for the other reason I stated: Write a complete sentence when answering. This qualifies at most as some loosely related words in some loosely defined order. I can't make out what you mean, and I doubt anyone else can. As such, I find it a low-quality answer (on an even lower quality question).